# Python execute sql file error pyodbc 'HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLExecDirectW)'

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

```py
    import sql_connect  

    def main():
        # check if db exists on target, if not create
        qry_create_db = "if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = '{}') create database {};".format('mydb','mydb')
        with sql_connect.conn:
            cur1 = sql_connect.cursor.execute(qry_create_db)
            cur1.commit() 

    main()

    def creation_table(filename):    
        # Open and read the file as a single buffer
        fd = open(filename, 'r')
        sqlFile = fd.read()
        fd.close()

        # all SQL commands (split on ';')
        sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

        # Execute every command from the input file
        for command in sqlCommands:
            with sql_connect.conn:
                cur2 = sql_connect.cursor.execute(command)
                cur2.commit()

    creation_table('Mypath\\schema\\TABLES\\TOSHBA.sql')
    creation_table('Mypath\\schema\\TABLES\\TALM_TYPE.sql')
```

This my python code that creates my database and my tables. The problem is when I execute my function

```py
"creation_table('Mypath\\schema\\TABLES\\TALM_TYPE.sql')"
```

I receive this error :

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

This my first sql file script TOSHBA that I execute first with my function creation_table and I have no error with it :

```sql
    USE mydb;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TOSHBA;

    CREATE TABLE TOSHBA
    (
    TOSHBA_WORK_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    WORK_NAME NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TOSHBA PRIMARY KEY  (TOSHBA_WORK_ID)
    );
```

And here the second sql script file with which I have the error:

```sql
    USE mydb;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TALM_TYPE;

    CREATE TABLE TALM_TYPE
    (
    TALM_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    TOSHBA_id INT NOT NULL,
    TALM_NAME NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TALM PRIMARY KEY (TALM_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FKֹ_TOSHBA_id FOREIGN KEY (TOSHBA_id) REFERENCES TOSHBA (TOSHBA_WORK_ID)
    );
```

Please help me to understand the error and to find the solution.

Python version : 3.7.3
Pyodbc version : 4.0.27

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Both scripts work fine for me with pyodbc 4.0.27 and Python 3.8.0. Please [edit] your question to provide additional details about your environment (Python version, pyodbc version, ODBC driver version, etc.).

Comment: One thing I notice in the second script is that `CONSTRAINT FKֹ_TOSHBA_id` contains a "Hebrew Point Holam" character (U+05B9). That shouldn't be a problem *per se* (as I said, the script works for me), but perhaps try deleting it from your copy and see if that helps.

Comment: I found the solution without understanding it. In the second sql script file, at the last line (');'), I didn't return to the next line and it caused an error. I also discovered that if I don't put the semicolon at the last line, I don't have the error. If somebody understand why it works when I return to the line or when I don't put the semicolon, I will enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

**It appears removing the last ';' from the sql file solves this issue.**

I'm not 100% on this but when I had this same issue and came here, I tried removing the last ';' from the sql script and it worked. So it seems that the .split() on the last ';' causes a blank line to be run through as a statement through the loop, whether there is another line there or not. As a blank line is not a valid sql statement.

In theory to work around this issue pragmatically you could either count the number of ; and only run the split that many times, or remove the last ; from the script before loading the statements. But both of these would be overload when you can just remove the last ';' in your sql file.