# Pyodbc can't parse query from iql file

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, impala

I have a docker image with a script which reads an iql file and executes it in impala. Removing the file reference and running a simple script works fine (ie SELECT 1;), but whenever I try to execute the script from a file I get an error

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : ParseException: Syntax error in line 2:\n\n^\nEncountered: EOF\nExpected: ALTER, COMMENT, COMPUTE, COPY, CREATE, DELETE, DESCRIBE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, INSERT, INVALIDATE, LOAD, REFRESH, REVOKE, SELECT, SET, SHOW, TRUNCATE, UPDATE, UPSERT, USE, VALUES, WITH\n\nCAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error\n (110) (SQLExecDirectW)'

I have tried removing DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16 from the cloudera.impalaodbc.ini file and various types of sql query (including changing the file extension to isql, iusql) but always  get the same error.

Any ideas?

Python function:

```
   def process_data_to_impala():
         conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='some_DSN', autocommit=True)
         crsr = conn.cursor()
         with open('/path/to/sql/file.iql','r') as inserts:
             for statement in inserts:
                crsr.execute(statement) 
                print(crsr.fetchall())
```

Comment: Inside your `for` loop, try `statement = statement.strip()` followed by `if statement:` before calling `crsr.execute(statement)`. That will ignore blank lines.

Comment: Thanks for you comment but this still returns the same error. I notice when I print statement I receive the query followed by a blank line and the the result of SELECT 1 (ie [(1, )] - could the loop be erroring out due to not closing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem relates to the way the python code is looping through the statement and the way ';' ends the query.

A better way to do it for a single query in a file is

```
   with open('file/location.iql') as script:
    statement = script.read()
    print(statement)
    crsr = conn.cursor()
    crsr.execute(statement)
```

And when you have multiple queries in a file and you need to loop:

```
    with open('file/location.iql') as script:
    sqlscript = script.read()
    for statement in sqlscript.split(';'):
        print(statement)
        crsr = conn.cursor()
        crsr.execute(statement)
```

When reading multiple queries from one script (ie Drop table, create table) you must remove ';' from the last query. This is because the split creates a final blank query after the last ';'. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323292/python-execute-sql-file-error-pyodbc-hy090-hy090-microsoftodbc-driver-m/73018997#73018997) for more info.

I hope this helps somebody in the future!